# ggplot boxplot: position_dodge does not work

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have made a relatively simple boxplot with ggplot

```
ggplot(l8tc.df_17_18,aes(x=landcover,y= tcw_17, group=landcover))+
geom_boxplot()+
geom_boxplot(aes(y= tcw_18),position_dodge(1))
```

A screenshot to get an idea of the data used:

[image: screenshot of data frame]

This is the output:

[image: boxplot]

I want the different boxplots to be next to each other and not in one vertical line. I have looked through all related questions and tried out a couple of options, however I could not find a solution so far.

I am still a ggplot beginner though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't post data as a picture! Use e.g. `dput` and select the relevant columns first. 
You'll probably have to transform your data into long format (e.g. with `gather` from `tidyr`) and set the group variable to your new variable.

Comment: `ggplot2` uses a long-format paradigm, in which you assign variables to visual elements, such as position. In this case, with long data you would map some grouping variable to create groups of boxplots. Dodging refers to groups of visuals; by just adding one `geom_boxplot` to another, there's no way to differentiate between those two groups, so dodge has no meaning.

Comment: @kath thanks for the hint of the "dput" function. I will use it from now on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use in this case different data format and melt it.

```
require(reshape2) 
require(tidyverse) 

# format data
melted_data <- l8tc.df_17_18 %>%
    select(landcover, tcw_17, tcw_18) %>%  
    melt('landcover', variable.name = 'tcw')

# plot
ggplot(melted_data, aes(x = as.factor(landcover), y = value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = tcw))
```

a dodge should be automatic but if you want ot experiment use `geom_boxplot(aes(fill = tcw), position = position_dodge())`
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html

you can write it in one line without creating temp file

```
l8tc.df_17_18 %>% 
    select(landcover, tcw_17, tcw_18) %>% 
    melt('landcover', variable.name = 'tcw') %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(landcover), y = value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = tcw))
```